# XML sitemap on large dynamic site

Tags: seo

I have a site in five languages with several 100.000s of pages. Every day about 10 to 50 new pages are added. 95% of these new pages contain news content (articles). How do I create a XML sitemap for a site like this? More specifically:

- I was thinking to let a spider go over the sections that are frequently updated. For all these sections I could make a separate sitemap. It could happen that the same URL is included in different sitemaps though. Is that a problem?
- Should I create a different sitemap for each language?
- How frequently do I ping Google?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. I was thinking to let a spider go over the sections that are frequently updated. For all these sections I could make a separate sitemap. It could happen that the same URL is included in different sitemaps though. Is that a problem?

Ans. No, having same URL in multiple sitemap is not a problem.

2. Should I create a different sitemap for each language?

Ans. Yes, That will be better and easy to maintain

3. How frequently do I ping Google?

Ans. Submit your sitemaps in "Google Search Console", it will automatically crawled by Google.

Use SiteMap Index for your multiple sitemap links https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/75712?hl=en

Limit your each XML sitemaps to 50,000 URLs